# App Store Connect "Impressions" analytics dropped to 0

Tags: app-store-connect

The "Impressions" analytics of my apps dropped to 0 since November 11. I observe that on all my apps in App Store Connect.
Has Apple changed anything on the analytics. Do you observe the same thing?

[image: App Store Connect Analytics]

Comment: Same here. It's bound to be some bug, of some kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening with nearly everyone.

if you notice the impressions is not `zero` but it is `-` (*see the image below*) which means it is not available at the moment.

[image]

This happens occasionally and then they fix it retroactively and they will fill old missing data.

Comment: You are right. The statistics appears today and the missing values have been completed. Thank you.